# WPF Listbox Selection change not firing on Item click

Tags: wpf, listbox, wpf-controls, listboxitem

In my wpf application when I select listboxItem, SelectionChanged event of listbox is not firing. However event fires when I click on outer margin.
have a look at below snap.

[image]

so basically, when I click on section inside Red border(Right Image), Selection change event is not firing, but when I click on outer border (White color part), selection change fires.

While searching about issue, I am not sure but I found it may be issue due to event tunneling. However I have only a bit of knowledge about tunneling yet.

So can any one please help me how this can get working so that selection change fire when I click on listboxitem (Red section)

let me if I need to further clear question. 
I am also putting listbox code here

```
<ListBox x:Name="Listbox1" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ListBoxItem Margin="10" Content="{Binding Name}" Height="25" 
                                             BorderBrush="#FF404040" BorderThickness="0,0.25" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't think of a reason why you would want to have a `ListBoxItem` inside the `DataTemplate` of a `ItemTemplate`. The `ListBoxItem`s are genarated automatically for each element of the `ListBox` and whatever you have in your DataTemplate will be used as the *content* of that `ListBoxItem` So in your case you end up having a `ListBoxItem` inside a `ListBoxItem`. This might be the cause.

Try it this way:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Listbox1" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Margin="10" 
                   Content="{Binding Name}" 
                   Height="25"
                   BorderBrush="#FF404040" 
                   BorderThickness="0,0.25" />
         </DataTemplate>                        
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks. I feel it was really a silly mistake I could not trace it out. anyways thanks again.

Comment: It seems so logical to use a ListBoxItem as template item in a ListBox ...